# What is the alternative to .ajax in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

In other words, I want to do a regular, non-AJAX request, but using Javascript. I'm researching this because I have to enable the back button in my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh? There is no "alternative". XMLHttpRequest is the only way of doing an HTTP request inside the page to my knowledge. If you want a synchronous request then do `async:false`.

You can do `location.href`, `history.pushState` or `window.open` but those aren't the same. You can also use jQuery bbq if you want back/forward.